# How to setup private/public keys and certificates for HTTPS server?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, private-key

I working to develop small HTTPS server that will be included in my android application. And the client will be browser. User can browse to the contain that I have on my HTTPS server. Can someone tell me what kind of setup do I need as far as the certificate and private/public keys are concerned. I am planning to use openssl to create my self-signed certificate.

FYI, I have initial setup done. And since my certificate is self-signed, browser displays warning to accept it on your own risk. So I believe server authentication is working. What do I need for server to authenticate the client ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem with hosting an HTTPS webserver on an android device is that the certificates are validated using a domain name. Without a domain name the client browser will display an error unless the server certificate is installed and trusted locally.

The two options are:

1. Register a domain name, use dynamic dns, and then request an ssl/tls certificate based on that name.
2. [Installing self-signed certificate programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957731/installing-self-signed-certificate-programmatically)

There is an Android library that supports https: http://tjws.sourceforge.net/